# How to plot hestia data

Tags: graph, plotly, python-xarray

I'm trying to find out how to plot Hestia data for 2015. Here's the file that I'm using, it's 200m resolution. https://data.nist.gov/od/id/686BF41FF1D773D3E0532457068166DD1903

So far I've tried this code.

```
    import xarray as xr
    import plotly.express as px
    o = xr.open_dataset("in2015.nc")
    ce=o["Carbon Emissions"]
    odf=o.to_dataframe()
    fig = px.choropleth_mapbox(odf, geojson=counties, color='Carbon Emissions', locations=odf.reset_index().index,color_continuous_scale="Viridis",range_color=(0, 12),mapbox_style="carto-positron",center={"lat": 39.7684, "lon": -86.1581}, zoom=9,opacity=0.5)
    fig.show()
```

It just shows a blank map. I also found in the README this

```
>min x coord: 141355.158472(west)
>min y coord: 1597073.12693(south)
>max x coord: 252903.718472(east)
>max y coord: 1704684.67893(north)
```